# How do I correctly check for a secure password?

Tags: passwords, javascript

I'm making an open-source web app that has login stuff in it.

I want to check on the server if the password is 'secure' (at least 8 characters, etc.).

The thing is that I'm not sure if I need something more than check for:

- at least 8 characters.
- uses numbers/special characters.

Comment: That depends on your security requirements and can't be answered definitively. We have lots of password-related questions here that might help you further.

Comment: Can you have provide a little more information such as OS Type, server password role etc?

Comment: Terminology: I believe you wish to check to see if a password is *strong* (not secure).

Comment: @Joe Whoops, I didnt really specify what I was talking about. See the edits

Comment: 8 character doesn't prevent dictionary attacks and [pwned passwords](https://haveibeenpwned.com)

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking. Are you asking for a password complexity policy that you want to enforce, or do you want to know how to enforce a password policy in your app? Checking strings is a simple programming question. As for what password policy to use, there are numerous documents and standards that have been published that you can use.

Comment: @schroeder I mean, a password policy.

Answer (score 1):

If not mistaken, you are asking how **strong** the server password(s) should be. As said in the comments, you are the only one who can answer that.

Those pages should help you out:

[SEC.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/what-is-worse-for-password-strength-a-poor-password-policy-or-no-password-polic)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength)

[Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994572(v=ws.11).aspx)

[Nist](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)

### Not in the question range

Your password(s) policies should meet the security requirements you have wisely established after assessed the risks. Here is a basic plain scheme :

```
        0 security           security requirements button        super secure
                 <------------------------[]-----------------------> 
user super friendly                                               Not user friendly at all
```

Here is the general idea : you have to define *the security requirements button position*. It's more or less a compromise between the ease of access and the security.